# JOINS vs. Group_Concat() - multiple one to many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, group-concat

I have a table `posts` which has a one to many relationship with multiple tables (`files` and `categories` in the completely simplified example below). `posts` also has many fields that it returns for each row.

If I am returning 1000 rows of `posts` and have 4 `files` and 3 categories per post, I will get 12000 records in the result set (duplicating the post info in order to give me the file info). This grows and grows with each one to many relationship.

Below shows an over simplified version of my current JOIN and also a contemplated Group_Concat() version. The Group_Concat method would simplify php handling tremendously.

Comments on performance of these two methods?

**Update** I realize that my main concern with the JOIN method is not the php code, but the server memory (& cpu resources?) that is consumed with processing a much larger result set. Each row can have a significant amount of data since I have a type `text` field.

**Using Joins**

```
SELECT p.postid, title, fileid, filename, category
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN files f ON f.postid = p.postid
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.postid = p.postid
```

**Using Group_Concat()**

```
select p.postid, title, (
    SELECT group_concat(
        concat_ws(",", fileid, filename)
        SEPARATOR ';') 
        FROM files f WHERE f.postid = p.postid
    ) as fileinfo
    SELECT group_concat(category) 
        FROM categories WHERE cat.postid = p.postid
    ) as catinfo
FROM posts p
```

Comment: Do you have any working PHP? I don't think it's hard to group concatenate the results in PHP using a loop. It'd be even easier with LINQ, but that's not available in PHP.

Comment: Execute both the query in phpmyadmin/workbench and check the execution time you can measure.

Comment: @siride Yes, I guess I exaggerate when I say it would "simplify php handling tremendously." Yes I currently loop through the results and extract the filenames to its own array, etc. However, the existing JOIN method creates thousands of (what I consider) unnecessary duplicate records. Aside from offending my aesthetic sense, I am curious to get a rough idea of the cpu and memory it consumes to use php to process thousands of records versus the performance hit of using Group_Concat instead, which produces a much cleaner and smaller result set.

Comment: @sandeepsure - Yes you are right. I can measure execution time. What I don't know is the impact of having thousands of rows of duplicate data being returned with each query (using JOINS). When does this become an issue with server memory and cpu resources? 1000 rows (with a significant number of bytes per row) versus 12000 rows for the same query seems like a big difference to me. And it can be a much larger difference as the number of one to many relationships increase.

Comment: Hope this might help to you http://www.hammerdb.com/about.html

Comment: @sandeepsure - I loaded hammerdb, but it uses its own schema and to test my own does not look trivial - modifying hammerdb scripts. But you've pointed me in the direction of looking for performance monitoring tools - probably something I need to do. I was hoping for someone's insight from experience. Thanks.